# PC2 of PCA by scikit-learn is unexpected

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I simplified my case.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
    [1., 1., 1.,],
    [1., 1., 1.,],
    [-1., -1., -1.,],
    [-1., -1., -1.,],
])
x_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
print('x_std...', x_std)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
y = pca.fit_transform(x_std)
print('y...', y)
```

The result is

```
x_std... [[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]]
y... [[ 1.73205081e+00  6.79869978e-17]
 [ 1.73205081e+00 -2.26623326e-17]
 [-1.73205081e+00  2.26623326e-17]
 [-1.73205081e+00  2.26623326e-17]]
```

I expected (PC1, PC2) values of first and second raw should be same but it didn't.

Second trial, I added raw to data.

```
data = pd.DataFrame([
    [1., 1., 1.,],
    [1., 1., 1.,],
    [1., 1., 1.,],
    [-1., -1., -1.,],
    [-1., -1., -1.,],
    [-1., -1., -1.,],
])
x_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
print('x_std...', x_std)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
y = pca.fit_transform(x_std)
print('y...', y)
```

The result is

```
x_std... [[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1.]]
y... [[ 1.73205081e+00  4.57971869e-16]
 [ 1.73205081e+00 -9.15943738e-17]
 [ 1.73205081e+00 -9.15943738e-17]
 [-1.73205081e+00  9.15943738e-17]
 [-1.73205081e+00  9.15943738e-17]
 [-1.73205081e+00  9.15943738e-17]]
```

Why PC2 value of first raw is weirdy?